# Tableview prototype cell not displaying items appended in array

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, append, checkmark

So here I made a class with two properties named Item. I am appending the item in the array but when I run the app I can only see two items: the first one and the last one. I appended five items. I can checkmark all 5 cells but only two items are displaying and one cell is not having a separating line.

[This is the simulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZ5e.png); as you can see no third item is showing but I can still check it and 3rd cell has no separator.

[image: Code]

Comment: Can I see *all* of the code in that class? It's likely an error in another part of the code. Also, next time, paste the code in the post instead of using an image with the formatting tools Stack Overflow provides. (also, I suggested an edit to the post with formatting changes to make it much easier to understand.)

Comment: hello thanks for your reply i just checked and found that i have made  a mistake on line 31 and 32.. but apart from it i do not understand why some of the cell's in simulator doesn't have the separator can't figure it out

Comment: You should really paste the code of the entire class instead of using an image.